# If the hero's x is between the enemy's x and the enemy's x plus his vision range, then attack

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math

I have an enemy ai question.

What I am trying to achieve is that

```
If(hero is  between enemie's x position and the enemies x position + 100( the max range) { then make enemy attack}
```

I want the enemy to fire when the hero is in the range area.

I have tried hitTestPoint but

```
if(hero.hitTestPoint(goblin,x + 100, goblin.y, true)
```

But this will be only true there is collision between the x and y points.

I want to stop using hitTestPoint and start using Math.

I've attempted,

```
if (_character.x > redGoblin.x && _character.x < redGoblin.x - 300)
```

But no results.

Any tips please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not good, you expect the character to be on the goblin's right and on the goblin's left at once.
This one must work:

```
if (_character.x > redGoblin.x && _character.x < redGoblin.x + 100)
```